# What's the Win32 API for doing "system compression" (CompactOS) on files?

Tags: winapi, ntfs

In addition to the bog-standard LZNT1 compression on NTFS, Windows 10 has a new form of compression called [system compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point#System_compression). This mode of compression is "optimized" for files that are read-only, namely executable files. It is used for the Compact OS feature, although one can also manually invoke it through `compact.exe /EXE`.

But what is the programmatic way to get and set the new type of compression status? I tried the old `FSCTL_GET_COMPRESSION` on the file, but it always gives 0 for `COMPRESSION_FORMAT_NONE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is what I have right now, after throwing `compact.exe` at Ghidra.

Besides the `FSCTL_GET_COMPRESSION` / `FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION` pair of `DeviceIoControl`, `compact` also calls [`FSCTL_GET_EXTERNAL_BACKING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/fsctl-get-external-backing) and [`FSCTL_SET_EXTERNAL_BACKING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/fsctl-set-external-backing). The documentation explains the compression information is stored in the [`FILE_PROVIDER_EXTERNAL_INFO_V1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_provider_external_info_v1) structure for the input/output. The fields are pretty well documented.

I am a bit too lazy to add a proper struct to Ghidra to verify this finding right now, but I am pretty sure this is the way.

---

A bit unorthodox is the way `compact.exe` calls the FSCTLs. Although the functions are documented to only use the NT APIs, the Win32 `DeviceIoControl` is used here and works just fine. The error codes are a bit strange, including undocumented stuff like 0x156 and 0x158. I need to find some time to throw stuff at `RtlNtStatusToDosError` before I dare to actually use these with Win32 handles.

FWIW, the set call is found at FUN_1400030e0 (0x158 and 0x13d are acceptable?), the get calls are at FUN_140002074 (0xea?) and FUN_1400040d, and a delete call is at FUN_1400040dc. This is for version 10.0.19041.1.